# The iTunes and iPad icon for my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons

I know the iTunes app store shows app icons much bigger and the iPad displays app icons bigger (including iphone apps on the ipad). But XCode wants a 57x57 image, and this would appear blurry in iTunes. Do i get a chance to upload a bigger picture at some point, or is there a different way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your application in iTunesConnect, you will have to upload a 512x512 icon for display in iTunes.

If you go to itunesconnect.apple.com, log in and check out the "Manage my Applications" section, it should answer a lot of the general questions regarding the submission process. (as well as create more questions ;) )